# How to close one of application window using Selenium winappdriver using java

Tags: winappdriver

Whenever i login to my windows desktop application, it opens 3 different window pages. Out of these one is homepage and rest of has other functionalities.
Here i want close other than home page windows using selenium windows application driver.

is there any specific functionality to closing the unwanted windows programmatically.

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.